# Can a non-bender take a piece of the Eternal Flame?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

Can a non-bender take a piece of the Eternal Flame?

Comment: Quote from fandom The Sun Warrior chief told them to `maintain the flame at a constant temperature` , as a small flame would go out, whereas a large flame would burn out of control. So yes if they had science tool to `maintain the flame at a constant temperature`

Answer (score 2):

A non-bender can do as much as every normal person in our world can do. But bringing the [Eternal Flame](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Eternal_Flame) to Ran and Shaw is an ancient ritual to learn the true nature of firebending. Thus, it would render the ritual useless if you took a piece of the flame with a candle or any other tool.

Comment: Does that mean that you _can't_ light a candle with the Eternal Flame, or merely that if you do light a candle you just end up with a lit candle that has no special properties?

Comment: The latter. @DavidW

Answer (score 0):

No, no no ran and shaw give you the power like wan he was a non bender but the lion turtle gave him the power of fire so I believe ran and shaw can give a non bender power and they can hold the eternal flame cause Aang couldn't fire bend so technically you can hold the eternal flame and also if the fire has been running for 1000 years then it probably is cold so you can hold it.

Comment: I don't really understand your last point, fire doesn't really get colder. Also could you [edit] in evidence to back this up, as I've mentioned on a few of your answers now. We try and provide answers backed in evidence here. You may also want to take the [tour] to learn a little more about the site.